# Can I find a print job's spool ID to find it in the spool/Printers directory?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, printer, print-server, printing

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server we are using as a `print server`.  We are encountering issues with some print jobs and I need to be able to look at a print job in one of printers and then go find the associated `.SPL` file in the c:\Windows\system32\spool\PRINTERS directory.

Is there an easy way to find the spool job number tied to a printer record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Event Viewer.

Expand "Applications and Services."

Expand "Microsoft."

Expand "PrintService."

Right-click on the Operational log and choose "Enable."

Now, new events will be generated in that event log.  When a job is sent through the spooler, the event will say "Spooling job 123."

That will be C:\Windows\System32\Spool\PRINTERS\00123.SHD and 00123.SPL.